# Sort field values alphabetically using marshmallow

Tags: python, python-3.x, marshmallow

I need to sort the values for each field alphabetically when they get returned by the API. It seems marshmallow's pre_dump method is the way to pre-process the data before serializing, but I haven't been able to figure this out. I've read the docs multiple times and Googled but haven't found the answer.

```
class UserSettingsSchema(UserSchema):
    class Meta:
        fields = (
            "id",
            "injuries",
            "channel_levels",
            "movement_levels",
            "equipments",
            "goals",
            "genres"
        )

    @pre_dump
    def pre_dump_hook(): # what do I pass in here?
        # alphabetize field values, eg, all the genres will be sorted

    equipments = fields.Nested(EquipmentSchema, many=True)
    goals = fields.Nested(GoalSchemaBrief, many=True)
    genres = fields.Nested(GenreSchemaBrief, many=True)
```

Comment: Please if this is the answer to your question accept, or else leave comments as to why it does not answer your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer given by PoP does not address the fact that I needed the values sorted. This is how I did it:

```
@post_load
def post_load_hook(self, item):
    item['genres'] = sorted(item['genres'])
    return item
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [the docs](http://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference.html):

> By default, receives a single object at a time, regardless of whether many=True is passed to the Schema.

Here's an example:

```
from marshmallow import *

class MySchema(Schema):

    name = fields.String()

    @pre_dump
    def pre_dump_hook(self, instance):
        instance['name'] = 'Hello %s' % instance['name']
```

Now you can do:

```
schema = MySchema()
schema.dump({'name': 'Bill'})

>>> MarshalResult(data={'name': 'Hello Bill'}, errors={})
```